# How to change the third party library using fork and commit with personal changes in iOS?

Tags: ios, git, swift3, git-fork

Currently i am using third party library for the floating label to the Text Field . The library with i am using is the floating label as defined in the below link:

https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects

Now i wish to use the cocoapods for using the library in the xcode project.
And i need to change the floating label by customising it. How to acheive the same by using the Fork option in Github?

Comment: Simply fork the repo in GitHub and then specify your forked repo in your podfile https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Comment: How to specify the fork in our pod file and after we get the pod we have to edit in the library which comes under pod??

Comment: Use the `git =>` operator. Eg. `pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'`

Comment: We have to paste this "pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'" in the pod file?

Comment: For example I got https://github.com/abhijithFirstFork/TextFieldEffects.git after forking so we have to include " pod "TextFieldEffects":git =>https://github.com/abhijithFirstFork/TextFieldEffects.git" in our pod file??

Comment: Yes. That is it.